# Not able to set android:paddingLeft using Android Databinding library

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-layoutparams

I am using Databinding library to update the views from view model object.

### activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.android.DataViewModel" />
    </data>

          <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingLeft="@{viewModel.setPaddingLeft}"
                android:paddingRight="@{viewModel.setPaddingLeft}"/>


</layout>
```

### ViewModel:

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:paddingLeft"})
public static void setPaddingLeft(View view, float paddingFloat) {
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding);
    view.setPadding(padding, view.getPaddingTop(), view.getPaddingRight(),
            view.getPaddingBottom());
}
```

I am getting below error:

Found data binding error(s):

**[databinding] {"msg":"Could not resolve com.example.android.DataViewModel.setPaddingLeft as an accessor or listener on the attribute."**

Comment: Change `android:paddingLeft="@{viewModel.setPaddingLeft}"` to `android:paddingLeft="@{(v)-> viewModel.setPaddingLeft(v)}"`

Comment: I am getting below arror after above changes:                                          
[databinding] {"msg":"Cannot find a setter for \u003ccom.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton android:paddingLeft\u003e that accepts parameter type \u0027lambda\u0027\n\nIf a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches."

Comment: Ok, another question, you are not using `float paddingFloat`, why declared it? Just put one parameter on your function and use your `android:paddingLeft="@{viewModel.setPaddingLeft}" `

Comment: If i pass only View parameter, i am getting below error:                                                                      error: @BindingAdapter setPaddingLeft(android.view.View) has 1 attributes and 0 value parameters. There should be 1 or 2 value parameters.                                                                           I tried with below code:                 android:paddingLeft="@{viewModel.setPaddingLeft}"